# converting a multivalued dependency into SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, functional-dependencies

Suppose we have the following MVD in the relation R(X,Y,Z):

```
X ->> YZ
```

Since I can write the FD `X -> Y` in SQL as such:

```
SELECT X
FROM R
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT Y) > 1
```

I try to apply the same logical thought to the MVD mentioned above:

```
SELECT X
FROM R AS R1
INNER JOIN 
R as R2
ON R1.X = R2.X
GROUP BY R1.X, R2.X 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT R1.B > 1) and COUNT(DISTINCT R1.C > 1)
```

but something doesn't look right to me, specially on the `JOIN` AND `HAVING` statements. Could someone please give a clue what's wrong here?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should only tag with one database.  If this is a generic SQL question, remove the specific database tags.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using `SQLite3`

Comment: I tagged this "functional-dependencies" rather than create a new "multivalued-dependencies" tag. I know the difference. I'm just not sure whether it makes sense to have another tag for mvds.

Comment: What are A,B and C? What do you mean, "write the FD"? And of what table? What do you want to analogously do for what table for MVD? Explain clearly and fully. "Write the FD" means nothing and for MVDS all we can do is guess from SQL that is *not* doing what you want.

Comment: Do you maybe want a yes/no query saying whether a given FD/MVD holds in a given table? [Eg.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352535/sql-statement-to-prove-that-a-b-in-a-rabcd)