# SQL statement to prove that a candidate key constraint holds in a R(ABCD)

Tags: sql, database, candidate-key

How do I write a SQL statement that proves the candidate key ACD holds  given a relation with attributes ABCD and the functional dependency A → B ?
I know there's something similar here: [SQL statement to prove that A->B in a R(ABCD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352535/sql-statement-to-prove-that-a-b-in-a-rabcd/16044590),
but can't figure out how to write the query for this constraint.

Comment: What you seem to mean is, show that if *{A → B} is a cover* then ACD is CK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\i tmp.sql
create table abcd(
        a integer not null
        ,b integer not null
        ,c integer not null
        ,d integer not null
        -- , PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c,d)
        );
INSERT INTO abcd(a,b,c,d)
select (s/4)%4, (s/4)%2,(s/2)%2,s%2
from generate_series(0,15) s
        ;
select *from abcd;

ALTER TABLE abcd ADD UNIQUE (a,b,c,d); --succeeds
ALTER TABLE abcd ADD UNIQUE (a,c,d); --succeeds
ALTER TABLE abcd ADD UNIQUE (b,c,d); --fails
```

---

Results:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 16
 a | b | c | d 
---+---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
 0 | 0 | 1 | 1
 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
 1 | 1 | 0 | 1
 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 0 | 0 | 0
 2 | 0 | 0 | 1
 2 | 0 | 1 | 0
 2 | 0 | 1 | 1
 3 | 1 | 0 | 0
 3 | 1 | 0 | 1
 3 | 1 | 1 | 0
 3 | 1 | 1 | 1
(16 rows)

ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  could not create unique index "abcd_b_c_d_key"
DETAIL:  Key (b, c, d)=(0, 0, 0) is duplicated.
```

---

`B` is functionally dependent on `A` here, but multiple `A`s can *point to* the same `B` value.

BTW: IMO it is impossible to *prove* something in SQL (it depends in the current data in the table(s)), but it may be possible to *reject* it. (by composing an example)